# igraph: summarize each node's neighbours characteristics

Tags: r, for-loop, igraph, neighbours

With an *igraph object* I would like to capture some features of each node's neighbours, for example the average degree of its neighbours.

I come up with this code, which is inelegant and quite slow.
How should I rethink it for large and complex networks?

```
library(igraph)

# Toy example
set.seed(123)
g <- erdos.renyi.game(10,0.2)

# Loop to calculate average degree of each node's neighbourhood
s <- character(0)
for(i in 1:gorder(g)){
  n <- ego_size(g, nodes = i, order = 1, mindist = 1)
  node_of_interest <- unique(unlist(ego(g, nodes = i, order = 1, mindist = 1)))
  m <- mean(degree(g, v = node_of_interest, loops = TRUE, normalized = FALSE)-1)
  
  s <- rbind(s,data.frame(node = i, neighbours = n, mean = m))

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding the data structure with `rbind` in a loop can get quite slow in R, because at every step it needs to allocate the space for the new object, and then copy it (see section 24.6 [here](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/perf-improve.html)). Also, you might be computing the degree of a node many times, if it s the neighbor of multiple nodes.

A possibly better alternative could be:

```
# add vertex id (not really necessary)
V(g)$name <- V(g) 

# add degree to the graph
V(g)$degree <- degree(g, loops = TRUE, normalized = FALSE)

# get a list of neighbours, for each node
g_ngh <- neighborhood(g, mindist = 1) 

# write a function that gets the means                       
get.mean <- function(x){
  mean(V(g)$degree[x]-1)
}

# apply the function, add result to the graph
V(g)$av_degr_nei <- sapply(g_ngh, get.mean)


# get data into dataframe, if necessary
d_vert_attr <- as_data_frame(g, what = "vertices")

d_vert_attr
   name degree av_degr_nei
1     1      0         NaN
2     2      1   2.0000000
3     3      2   1.0000000
4     4      1   1.0000000
5     5      2   1.0000000
6     6      1   1.0000000
7     7      3   0.6666667
8     8      1   0.0000000
9     9      1   0.0000000
10   10      0         NaN
```